# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so

Tags: php, macos, osx-yosemite, mcrypt

I've just got a new mac with yosemite 10.10.4 installed. PHP version 5.5.24 is installed and apache is configured. I can envoke php on localhost. 
When i want to run php artisan in terminal I keep getting this error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mcrypt.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

I've tried to install mcrypt. I can find the `mcrypt.so` in `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`.

I've tried to move the `mcrypt.so` file from `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626` into `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212` which is the folder that php references to. But that of course doesn't work and I get the error that php and mcrypt are compiled differently.

Maybe a reinstall of php could work, but I can't seem to find a solution to that.

Hope that someone can shed a light on this issue. I've spend a lot of hours on trying different things.

Thanks in advance.

BO

Comment: I have no idea about OSX environments, but this reads as if the package you installed simply is broken / incomplete. Maybe you want to build it yourself, or you have to wait until it gets fixed.

Comment: Yes, maybe. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If I had a mac and needed to run a local server, I'd install MAMP (https://www.mamp.info/en/). I'm not sure if that will help your problem but MAMP makes it easy to manage apache, mysql and php on mac